# Azure Functions Apps combined with a Self-Hosted Integration Runtime

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

We developed an Azure Function generating some files. We would like to copy these files to a on-premise SMB-share. This SMB-share has been made available by an on-premise self-hosted integration runtime.

Is it possible to copy files from an Azure Function to an on-premise SMB-share through an on-premise self-hosted integration runtime? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to copy files from an Azure Function to an on-premise SMB-share through an on-premise self-hosted integration runtime. You can follow the below steps:

1. First, Configure the on-premise self-hosted integration runtime to connect to the on-premise SMB-share. You can do this by installing the integration runtime on a machine that has access to the SMB-share, and then configuring the SMB-share as a linked service in Azure Data Factory.
2. In your Azure Function, use the Azure File Storage API to write the files to an Azure File Share. You can create a new file share using the Azure Storage Explorer or the Azure Portal.
3. Create an Azure Data Factory pipeline that copies the files from the  Azure File Share to the on-premise SMB-share. You can use the "Copy Data" activity in Azure Data Factory to do this. In the linked service for the source, select the Azure File Share you created in step 2. In the linked service for the destination, select the SMB-share you configured in step 1.
4. Trigger the Azure Data Factory pipeline from your Azure Function. You can use the Azure Data Factory REST API to trigger the pipeline from your Azure Function.

Comment: That's indirectly, so does it mean an Azure Function cannot directly connect to a data store via a self-hosted integration runtime?